# dependent drop down for Pricing Minimum to maximum dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dependencies

I've been stalking here for longer than I can remember, this is my first post so I hope i get this right. I want to be able to have a Minimum and Maximum Price Dropdowns, and when someone selects a minimum price it is to auto-update the Maximum Price with the minimum value selected. here's my code so far... (taken from a previous post by someone else but I can get it to work properly. It is working in theory, but if i select say £90,000.00 it remove everything that contains a number less than a 9.

I guess I need to know how to get the Javascript to treat it as a number/numeric so it knows that 110000 is higher than 90000

```
$(window).load(function(){
var maxprice = $('#maxprice').html();
$('#minprice').change(function() {
$('#maxprice').html(maxprice);
$('#maxprice option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() <= $('#minprice').val()) $(this).remove();
});
});
});

<div><select name="minprice" class="searchboxes" id="minprice">
<option value="0">No Minimum</option>
<?php for ($n = 10000; $n <= 250000; $n += 10000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>        </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 275000; $n <= 500000; $n += 25000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 550000; $n <= 1000000; $n += 50000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 1100000; $n <= 2500000; $n += 100000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 3000000; $n <= 5000000; $n += 250000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 5000000; $n <= 15000000; $n += 500000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?></select></div>

<div><select name="maxprice" class="searchboxes" id="maxprice">
<option value="0">No Maximum</option>
<?php for ($n = 10000; $n <= 250000; $n += 10000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 275000; $n <= 500000; $n += 25000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 550000; $n <= 1000000; $n += 50000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 1100000; $n <= 2500000; $n += 100000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 3000000; $n <= 5000000; $n += 250000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
<?php for ($n = 5000000; $n <= 15000000; $n += 500000) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $n; ?>"><?php echo number_format($n, 2, '.', ','); ?>    </option><?php  } ?>
</select></div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

`if (parseInt($(this).val()) <= parseInt($('#minprice').val())) $(this).remove();`

Comment: Wow! Wow! Wow! Thank you so much. that seems to have worked a treat! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I think I may have found my favourite forum! thank you so much.